# Automatically save iMessages on MacBook as soon as they are sent or received on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, icloud, messages, messages-in-icloud

I sometimes have to delete an iMessage text thread on my iPhone pretty much immediately after replying to it.

I have iMessage "enabled from iCloud" on my Mac and text forwarding from my iPhone, but I think if I delete texts on my iPhone they're also immediately deleted on my Mac.

I'd like to be able to keep those texts on my Mac and usually I don't have time to save them manually before deleting them on my phone.

Is there anything I can do? Can those texts be automatically stored on my HD somewhere? Any other solution?

Comment: With iMessages in the cloud all devices stay in sync (that's the entire point of it really). If you want to delete messages on one device and have them remain on the other you'll have to disable Messages in iCloud.

Comment: @KevinGrabher, thank you I just figured it out. Do you know by any chance...I now have text forwarding set up to my Mac and "enable messages in icloud" turned off on my Mac, which i think is what I want (get all sent/received msgs on iPhone archived on my Mac where they won't be deleted if I delete them on my iPhone).
It seems to be working for the most part, however I'm missing some Messages on my Mac, some of them didn't get forwarded. Do I need to keep my Mac on all the time? Will it not get messages if it's even sleeping or the display is off? Is it something else?

Comment: Past messages will not get uploaded to the Mac. The setting of forwarding messages will only apply to new messages. I'm not sure what happens to messages that you receive while not in proximity to the Mac.

Comment: @KevinGrabher, thank you for the fast reply. I think some messages haven't been forwarded since I setup text forwarding and turned messages in iCloud off. Is that possible? Will I get forwarded messages even if my Mac is off?

Comment: "As long as your iPhone is turned on and connected to Wi-Fi or a cellular network, new SMS/MMS texts can be sent and received on the devices that you added." https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208386